# When should I use "performBlock" method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, objective-c-blocks

I use CoreData and I try to make an asynchronous fetch request.
Explain me please, why I should use "performBlock" method in that case

```
[managedObjectcontext performBlock:^{
    [managedObjectcontext executeRequest:asyncFetch error:&err];
}];
```

if that way works as well?

```
[managedObjectcontext executeRequest:asyncFetch error:&err];
```

And what benefits of using the first one with "performBlock"?

Comment: try turning on core data thread debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: are used to send messages to your NSManagedObjectContext whether the MOC was initialized using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. If you do anything with one of these context types,  you do it in a block.

performBlock: will add the block to the backing queue and schedule it to run on its own thread. You might use this for long persist operations as this block will return immediately

performBlockAndWait: will also add the block to the backing queue and schedule it to run on its own thread. However, the block will not return until the block is finished executing, hence, it is a blocking call.

Comment: can you please cite some reference or link as I need to learn it in detail.

Comment: You can read the apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/ . Also, I recommend http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93355099502/performblock-vs-performblockandwait